# APK Expansion Files - Downloader Library not support Android Oreo and Android studio version 3.2?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I believe that the original APK Expansion Library was slightly over-engineered. And not support android Oreo.

> **First:**
>   I'm trying to use Google's Downloader Library and Application Licensing Service since my app is going to use APK Expansion.
>   I read guide from https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files#java and https://kitefaster.com/2017/02/15/expansion-apk-files-android-studio/,Everything is going well. But error.expansion.downloader does not exist. I did everything as  guide
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYybY.png) , [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvJEE.png) , [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkFpE.png)
>
> **Final**
>   , I have used lib from git-hub [https://github.com/bolein/better-apk-expansion](https://github.com/danikula/Google-Play-Expansion-File)
>   But it always status IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED_FETCHING_URL when download OBB file and it not support Android Oreo with error toast Developer warning for package  Failed to post notification on channel .
>   Code download OBB file:

```
        if (!expansionFilesDelivered()) {

        try {
            Intent launchIntent = SampleDownloaderActivity.this
                    .getIntent();
            Intent intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification = new Intent(
                    SampleDownloaderActivity
                    .this, SampleDownloaderActivity.this.getClass());
            intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setAction(launchIntent.getAction());

            if (launchIntent.getCategories() != null) {
                for (String category : launchIntent.getCategories()) {
                    intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.addCategory(category);
                }
            }

            // Build PendingIntent used to open this activity from
            // Notification
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    SampleDownloaderActivity.this,
                    0, intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            // Request to start the download
            int startResult = DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(this,
                    pendingIntent, SampleDownloaderService.class);

            if (startResult != DownloaderClientMarshaller.NO_DOWNLOAD_REQUIRED) {
                // The DownloaderService has started downloading the files,
                // show progress
                initializeDownloadUI();
                return;
            } // otherwise, download not needed so we fall through to
              // starting the movie
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot find own package! MAYDAY!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        validateXAPKZipFiles();
    }
```

I hope somebody give me a solution, please.

---

Answer (score 1):

Try moving to the latest expansion code from Github. Google haven't updated their docs yet. The code is at: https://github.com/google/play-apk-expansion

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know your problem, but my below code is using  [play-apk-expansion](https://github.com/google/play-apk-expansion) and working fine.
just note that when using emulator to use google play supported Image.

```
void check_apkx(){
    if (!expansionFilesDelivered()) {
        try {                  
            Intent launchIntent = MainActivity.this.getIntent();
            Intent intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification = new Intent(
                    MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this.getClass());
            intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setAction(launchIntent.getAction());

            if (launchIntent.getCategories() != null) {
                for (String category : launchIntent.getCategories()) {
                    intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.addCategory(category);
                }
            }
            // Build PendingIntent used to open this activity from
            // Notification
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    0, intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            // Request to start the download
            DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(this,
                    pendingIntent, SampleDownloaderService.class);

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
//            validateXAPKZipFiles();


    }
```